# Split page vertically using CSS

Tags: css, html

Sorry guys for the really simple question but I have tried to float one div left and one right with predefined widths along these lines

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="float:left; width: 80%">
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Although this 'mostly' works it seems to mess up the other elements on the page below it.

So what is the correct why to split a HTML page vertically into two parts using CSS without effecting other elements on the page?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

you can use..

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
   <div style="float:left; width: 80%">
   </div>
   <div style="float:right;">
   </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

now element below this will not be affected.

Comment: While this would work, it's considered bad practice to add elements whose only function is to "clear content".

Comment: What's the best practice in these cases then? (I've been wondering for a while how to avoid "clearfix" divs)

Comment: what if I need a line between them? can't use left|right border since I don't know which one will be larger all the time...

Answer (score 15):

Just add overflow:auto; to parent div

```
<div style="width: 100%;overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:left; width: 80%">
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G6N5T/3/)**

Comment: you just put `height: 400px;` on both sides.

Comment: Thank you for the working example! For some reason, yours worked and the accepted didn't. I wonder why...

Answer (score 10):

I guess your elements on the page messes up because you don't clear out your floats, check this out

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6N5T/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floatleft"></div>
    <div class="floatright"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
}

.floatleft {
    float:left; 
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    height: 400px;
}

.floatright {
float: right;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    height: 400px;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There can also be a solution by having both `float` to `left`.

Try this out:

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sUtvd/3/)

P.S. This is just an improvement of Ankit's Answer

Comment: Awesome demo made! Made things working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/G6N5T/1574/

## ***CSS/HTML code***:

```css
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.fleft {
    float:left; 
    width: 33%;
background:lightblue;
    height: 400px;
}

.fcenter{
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    background:lightgreen;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:0.25%;
}

.fright {
float: right;
    background:pink;
    height: 400px;
    width: 33.5%;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <!--Updated on 10/8/2016; fixed center alignment percentage-->
    <div class="fleft">Left</div>
    <div class="fcenter">Center</div>
    <div class="fright">Right</div>
</div>
```

This uses the CSS `float` property for left, right, and center alignments of `div`s on a page.

Comment: This snippet is just a modification of [this JSFiddle (click me!)](http://jsfiddle.net/G6N5T/).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also use a special function known as the **linear-gradient()** function to split browser screen into two equal halves.
Check out the following code snippet:

```
body
{
  background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, lightblue 50%, skyblue 50%);
}
```

Here, **linear-gradient()** function accepts three arguments

1. `90deg` for **vertical** division of screen.( Similarly, you can use `180deg` for horizontal division of screen)
2. `lightblue` color is used to represent the left half of the screen.
3. `skyblue` color has been used to represent the right half of the split screen.
   Here, `50%` has been used for **equal** division of the browser screen. You can use any other value if you don't want an **equal** division of the screen.
   Hope this helps. :)
   Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the flex-box approach:**

**CSS**

```
 .parent {
  display:flex;
  height:100vh;
  }
  .child{
    flex-grow:1;
  }
  .left{
    background:#ddd;
  }
  .center{
    background:#666;
  }

  .right{
    background:#999;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child left">Left</div>
    <div class="child center">Center</div>
    <div class="child right">Right</div>
</div>
```

You can try the same in [js fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ojLb254z/)