# Columns On A Webpage Made With CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I am creating a webpage, and I'm unsure of how to do something. I did a bit of research, and was unable to find an answer. Basically, I would like to split the body of my page into two columns. On the left side, I want to put pictures, and on the right, I would like to put text. How do I do this? Please provide a simple explanation, I'm a new to web design

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split page vertically using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662536/split-page-vertically-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support older versions of IE, you can use 'flex' layout.

See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
#pics,
#text {
  flex: 1;
  color: white
}
#pics {
  background-color: blue;
}
#text {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="pics">
    Pics here
  </div>
  <div id="text">
    Text here
  </div>
<div>
```