# Is it possible to place two grid side by side?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

So here is my problem. I use some ui-grid on my interface to show information, but I would like to have 2 grid of 3 columns side by side (aligned vertically). So far, I haven't found exemple of it and i tried to code it, but without success. Is there someone here with better experience then me who knows how its possible? So far, that's what i thought about the solution :

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false">
    <li data-role="list-divider">
            <div class="ui-grid-b" style="width: 50%">
                <div class="ui-block-a">Header 1</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">Header 2</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">Header 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-b" style="width: 50%; float: right">
                <div class="ui-block-a">Header 1</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">Header 2</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">header 3</div>
            </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I just try to get two table side by side like this one:https://jsfiddle.net/8o39tqgz/1/

**EDIT**

Just tried display: inline, but it doesn't work on the same line... https://jsfiddle.net/s71zpcgs/

Comment: do you want a 2 grids, each grid with 3 inner grids... all horizontally aligned, just that?

Comment: 2 grids, with each 3 columns, aligned horizontally

Comment: what do you mean by horizontally aligned? one next of other?

Comment: Just like this http://postimg.org/image/vc3bz0lrv/

Comment: did you try making the divs `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: Why is there a jquery tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its not exactly what I wanted, but that will do it. Ty to @ezanker for the solution :

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header">
     <h1>My page</h1> 
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" class="gridUL">
<li data-role="list-divider">
            <div class="ui-grid-a bothGrids">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <table class="halfGrid" style="width: 98%" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr><th>header 1</th><th>header 2</th><th>header 3</th></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td>content 1</td><td>Some bigger content in this cell</td><td>content 3</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>content 1</td><td>content 2</td><td>content 3</td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b ">
                   <table class="halfGrid" style="width: 98%">
                         <thead>
                            <tr><th>header 1</th><th>header 2</th><th>header 3</th></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td>content 1</td><td>content 2</td><td>content 3</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>content 1</td><td>content 2</td><td>content 3</td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

</li></ul>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.halfGrid {
margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 1%;
border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;

}

.halfGrid td, .halfGrid th {
border: 1px solid #aaa;
padding: 4px;
text-align: center;
width: 33%;
font-weight: normal;
white-space: normal;
}
.halfGrid th {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

Actually, I got the idea of splitting the screen in two and wrap one table in each side and that work exactly as I wanted! Im so happy, I was working on it for many hours... Felt like running in circle, but its finally done! Here is the code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="fleft">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" style="min-width:350px">
                <li data-role="list-divider">
                    <div class="ui-grid-b">
                        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">PN</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Amendment</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Designation</div>
                    </div>
                </li>

            <!-- Data found -->
                <li> 
                    <a href="javascript:alert('Hello world');">
                        <div class="ui-grid-b">
                            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">Info1</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Info2</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Info3</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="fright">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" style="min-width:350px">
                <li data-role="list-divider">
                    <div class="ui-grid-b">
                        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">PN</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Amendment</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Designation</div>
                    </div>
                </li>

            <!-- Data found -->
                <li> 
                    <a href="javascript:alert('Hello world');">
                        <div class="ui-grid-b">
                            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">Info1</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Info2</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Info3</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap
{
width: 100%;
overflow:auto;
padding:2px;
}
.fleft 
{
float:left; 
width: 50%;
}
.fright
{
float: right;
width: 50%;

}
```

Found solution in this post : [Split page vertically using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662536/split-page-vertically-using-css) and integrated the part of my code. Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/G6N5T/1211/

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false">
    <li data-role="list-divider">
            <div class="ui-grid-b" style="width: 50%; float: left">
                <div class="ui-block-a column" >Header 1</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b column" >Header 2</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c column" >header 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-b" style="width: 50%; float: left">
                <div class="ui-block-a column" >Header 1</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b column" >Header 2</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c column" >header 3</div>
            </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then at your css add this

```
.column{
   width:33%;
   float:left;
   /* you can optionally set a fixed height */
}
```

Comment: Isnt it one useless </div>? And the problem with the result is that the head  is in one block with all 6 titles. I need 2 separated table, just like that http://postimg.org/image/vc3bz0lrv/

Comment: You can set a margin between ui-grid-a and ui-grid-b

Comment: Well, the margin can be usefull, but my biggest problem is having 2 differents grid side-by-side

Comment: you might mean you want to align them VERTICALLY?

Comment: That's actually what im looking for, but with the style of the list-divider. I did read a while ago that there is a default style... maybe I can include it in a regular div to have the good result.

Answer (score 0):

You could nest two 3 column grids within one 2 column grid:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" class="gridUL">
    <li data-role="list-divider">
        <div class="ui-grid-a bothGrids">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <div class="ui-grid-b halfGrid">
                    <div class="ui-block-a cell">header 1</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b cell">header 2</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c cell">header 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b ">
                <div class="ui-grid-b halfGrid">
                    <div class="ui-block-a cell">Header 1</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b cell">Header 2</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c cell">header 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

.halfGrid {
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.halfGrid .cell {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8o39tqgz/3/)**

Comment: Oh so close actually, but as you can see, its still the same header. The <li> tag is putting all the headers together. Im looking for something like that and i dont know if its possible : http://postimg.org/image/vc3bz0lrv/

Comment: @MacGruber, do you need the listview?

Comment: Well I use this form in order to have the style of the list-divider. If I can have a table with the same style, that would be good.